# How to get span tag value using robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

This is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="near-matches">
 
  <b class="item">8</b> ==$0
```

I am trying to get value '8' using xpath and get text keyword in robot framework but it is not returning any value. This is what i tried.

```
${response}    get  text    xpath=//b[@class="item"]
Log    Num Value is ${response}
```

But this is not returning any value. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: The title mentions a `span` tag, but the code shows a `div`. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
${value} =  Get Text  css=b.item
Log To Console  ${value}
```